# Why is caret assuming BestModel = the one who minimize the CV-metric and not the minimum+1se like in LASSO?

Tags: r, lasso-regression

Usually, when approaching to LASSO, the best hyperparameter lambda is assumed to be lambda.1se (in the glmnet package), which is the lambda minimizing/maxining the CV-metric (usually AUC, Accuracy or Deviance) PLUS 1 standard deviation.
lamnda.1se = lambda.min + sd(lambda.min)

In this way there is a stronger penalization and the model is less prone to overfitting.

However, in caret, I always find the assumption that the best model is the corresponding to the min/max of the CV-metric. Is it wise?

Is there a way to ask caret train function to select the model corresponding to lambda.1se?

Thank you.